# jquery to grab link and text based on class

Tags: jquery, arrays, find, hyperlink

I'm trying to use jquery to grab the entire link depending on it's class.

Here's my code:

```
<ul class="vm_catTigra">
  <li><a class="mainlevel" href="/index.php&amp;category_id=6">AAAAA</a></li>
  <li><a class="mainlevel" href="/index.php&amp;category_id=10">BBBBB</a></li>
  <li><a class="sublevel" href="/index.php&amp;category_id=11">CCCCC</a></li>
  <li><a class="sublevel" href="/index.php&amp;category_id=12">DDDDD</a></li>
  <li><a class="mainlevel" href="/index.php&amp;category_id=13">EEEEE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's what I want jquery to grab for me (in an array):

```
<a class="mainlevel" href="/index.php&amp;category_id=6">AAAAA</a>
<a class="mainlevel" href="/index.php&amp;category_id=10">BBBBB</a>
<a class="mainlevel" href="/index.php&amp;category_id=13">EEEEE</a>
```

I have tried using this:

```
var mainlevel = [];
jQuery(".mainlevel").each(function() { 
  mainlevel.push(jQuery(this).html());
});
```

But it is returing AAAAA, BBBBB, EEEEE instead of the full line of code that I'm after.

Comment: I have been looking for what I'm trying to acheive and the best I can get is AAAAA, BBBBB, EEEEEE. Not the entire line in an array. Hense coming here for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like this:

```
var linkArray = $("a.mainlevel").map(function() {
    return $(this).parent().html();
}).get()​​​​​​;
```

[You can view a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/qb9TU/), the `.get()` on the end makes it so you get the native array object at the end...this will result in a 3 string array like your question :)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$('a.mainlevel')
```

Or if there are more of those on the page and you only want the ones in that list:

```
$('.vm_catTigra a.mainlevel')
```

You should have a read of the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: it is an array.  $('a.mainlevel') returns an array of length 3 with all 3 anchor elements in it.  you can test it out by placing a watch on $('a.mainlevel')[0], $('a.mainlevel')[1], $('a.mainlevel')[2]

Comment: @John - If I understand correctly, she wants the html string of the entire link, so a 1x3 array of strings, not elements....I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate in each li and get the innerhtml then store them on an array
like this.

```
var arr = ""; 
var arr_i = 0;
$(".mainlevel parent").each(function(){
  arr[arr_i] = $(this).html();
  arr_i++;
});
```

hope this helps

Comment: This isn't valid JavaScript syntax, or jQuery :)

Comment: aha.. sorry.. forgotten the quotes

Comment: Your `arr` is a string, not an array, also the `.each()` closure function already gets an index, it's the first parameter passed to the function, you could reduces to this: `var arr = []; $(".mainlevel").each(function(i){ arr[i] = $(this).html(); });`, but `parent` isn't a valid selector (that would look for `<parent>` elements inside the anchors), you need to access the parent in the loop, you can see my answer for how to do this.